# how do you execute ssh commands that has variables in them in php

Tags: php

I need to execute commands over ssh in php. Sincere there are multiple of servers, I have to build the $file_name for each server. File name is like this: vmstat_servername. Below is the code.

```
$file_name="/var/vmstat_".$value;
```

this command is not working because the $file_name inside the single tikcs. Any ideas how I can make this work?

```
$line1= $ssh->exec('head -3 $file_name');
```

Comment: you can use double-ticks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use double quotes, so that the variable will be evaluated:

```
$line1= $ssh->exec("head -3 $file_name");
```